# QGIS one to many join issue

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, attribute-joins, one-to-many

I already asked in previous question [QGIS table join issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331647/qgis-table-join-issue), how to join shape file data and CSV data which contain multiple ***SAME ID*** for one object?

*Shape file contains columns: object id, area, height etc*

*CSV contains columns: object id, materials as brick, metal, concrete etc*

So first I was joining them by ***JOIN*** option, but the numbers did not match as the software only recognises one value of the field and overwrites it to all other same IDs.

I was offered solution ***Project>Properties>Relations*** and I used instructions on: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#id40. But I have over ***84000*** rows and don't have time to go through all of them and make connections. Further this option does not seem to have all the information I need for example in the attribute table. I would ideally like to be able to do this one-to-many join such that I could have overview of each material (concrete, steel, brick etc) for each field (I did not figured that out with relation).

Join table would be ideal but as stated the numbers do not match so it is issue with representation. Also it is important to have all materials for each field as they will be intersected with different layers and the correct amounts are needed for further calculations.

Comment: Did u really mean **84000** fields _(=columns)_ ?

Comment: No, sorry I meant rows.

Comment: I have about 15 columns

Answer (score -1):

One way to get there is to open the .dbf (d-base file) and the .csv as a data frame in R, then merge the tables and overwrite the original .dbf with the joined data.

```
#dependency
install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign) 

#read in d-base table
df.1 <- read.dbf('**pathtotable1.dbf**')

#read in .csv file
df.2 <- read.csv('**pathtotable2.csv**')

#merge tables based on commmon ID field
m = merge(df.1, df.2, by="**YOURIDFIELD**", all.x = FALSE,  all.y = FALSE)

#overwrite original .csv file
write.dbf(m, "**pathtotable1.dbf**', factor2char = TRUE, max_nchar = 254)
```

Comment: dBase-III has a documented limit of 100 fields and a hard limit of 255 fields.  It is not possible to write 84,000+ fields to a shapefile.  There's also a 4000 byte transfer buffer limit on the dBase specification, so even if that many fields were permitted, they couldn't be wider than 0.38 bits each.

Comment: @vince Given the clarifications in the comments above (IE that this data has only 15 columns, not 84000) is this now a viable solution?

Comment: @Cory what do you mean dbf file? I am not sure about d-base file, I am mac user.

Comment: @csk Big difference on 84k fields vs. 84k rows, but using Excel on a shapefile's dBase file is still a recipe for disaster, especially in the hands of a novice -- too many opportunities to corrupt/reorder the row count and completely lose association between features and attributes.  I didn't downvote, but I can't upvote either.

Comment: @JulijaM When you create a shapefile in ESRI's shapefile format (.shp), there are some other files that are created alongside it. Namely, an index file (.shx) and a d-base table (.dbf). The table can be edited according to your desired additions in a more manipulable format (i.e. .csv), then rewritten as a .dbf table so that the main shapefile (.shp) will reflect the changes.

Comment: @Vince you are right, I changed the code to recommend an R-only solution.

Comment: @Cory when I merge the file I have 120 892 entries not 84000. Which makes my materials doubled, and again is something I want to avoid. Any other ideas?

Comment: I already tried duplicate and unique, but it does not seem to work

Comment: And I tried all of these options <http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/join-in-r-merge-in-r/> but still the same duplicated rows

Comment: @JulijaM Try it again now that I changed the merge operation to make it exclude the extra rows.

Comment: @Cory still the same

Comment: OK I think I understand what is happening. Some of your features in the shapefile are made from more than one type of material, so the ID numbers for those features occur multiple times in the output tables. Does this sound correct?

Comment: @Cory, not exactly. The IDs do not have anything with materials. They represent ID for each polygon/structure. Shapefile is provided by municipality. Why they have same IDs for multiple structures? Because on 1 parcel (1 owner) there are multiple structures but they all have the same ID, as they are connected to that same parcel/owner. In the shapefile there are only attributes as building type, district, height, area etc.

Comment: Then I got another set of data (csv) from a fellow, which contained objects/polygons/structures (same multiple IDs as in shapefile) with assigned representative materials intensities (amounts) to each structure (as said above in comment they are not the same in shape or height therefore different quantities). As the IDs are not unique for each polygon QGIS merges them using only first ID. But I need to avoid that so my amounts from excel matches the one when joined to QGIS. I am not sure if I am explaining ti correctly anymore :(

Comment: All the features have more than 1 material analysed, and because they are residential and non-residential buildings they all will have more or less the same materials. In the end there is total of material stock which does not correspond to the original calculations